# Aggregating dropwizard timer metrics

Tags: java, monitoring, dropwizard, influxdb, grafana

I'm currently working on monitoring system for my application that consists of several independent microservices. I'm using [dropwizard-metrics](https://github.com/dropwizard/metrics) for collecting data from JVMs, [InfluxDB](https://github.com/influxdata/influxdb) for storing and [Grafana](https://github.com/grafana/grafana) for creating nice-looking graphs.

One of my goals is creating simple dashboard that will present how my application performs. So I have to aggregate metrics from each of microservice in order to have global view.

Some metrics are easy to aggregate, e.g. sum of active database connections. I have problem with aggregating [timer metric](http://metrics.dropwizard.io/3.1.0/getting-started/#timers) that I want to somehow simple visualize, e.g. I'm interested in aggregating percentiles of response times of systems that my application depends on from all my microservices instances.

I think this is very common case. Do you have any advice? I've read [blog post](https://lab.getbase.com/aggregating-response-time/) about it but it doesn't cover my case.

Answer (score 0):

A dropwizard metrics timer already does aggregation. What you want ideally is to no pre-aggregate in your metrics collecting application unless absolutely nessecary. You can do aggregation (percentiles, etc.) later in Grafana.